# storing user-entered info within a modal

Tags: discord.py

To elaborate on the title, I've created an embed system using modals and buttons. Once the buttons are clicked on, the modal pops up and whatever is entered there edits the embed part accordingly. This issue is, for example, when I click the button to edit footer text and/or timestamp, I would edit the text then later on re-click the button to add timestamp to the embed, but once I do this the footer text is cleared/removed.

How can I store/keep the information the user entered within the modal so when the user goes to click it, all of their previous inserted text will still be there?

```
class footer(ui.Modal, title="Edit Footer"):
        ftext = ui.TextInput(label="Edit footer text", placeholder="Encourage life", style=discord.TextStyle.long, required=False)
        fticon = ui.TextInput(label="Edit footer image", placeholder="https://www.chickenCLT.png", style=discord.TextStyle.long, required=False)
        time = ui.TextInput(label="Timestamp", placeholder="Yes/No", style=discord.TextStyle.short, min_length=2, max_length=6, required=False)

        async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
            embed = interaction.message.embeds[0]
            if self.ftext:
                embed.set_footer(text=self.ftext.value, icon_url=self.fticon.value)

            if self.time.value.lower() == "yes":
                embed.timestamp = datetime.now()
            else:
                embed.timestamp = None

            await interaction.message.edit(embed=embed)
            await interaction.response.send_message(".", delete_after=0.0001)

class MainView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @discord.ui.button(label="Edit Footer", style=discord.ButtonStyle.grey, custom_id="edit_footer")
    async def edit_footer(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        await interaction.response.send_modal(footer())
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to retain past responses in the modal input boxes? Based on your code, the embed should edit just fine

Comment: @Raymus yes i want the code to retain the past responses because anytime someone would go edit the timestamp the footer is edited/removed which i don't want. i just want to make it easier so users can edit only one part and not have to edit everything else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the modal fields to be pre-populated with existing data, enabling quick editing, set the parameter [default](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.ui.TextInput.default) when creating your `TextImput`.

```
class footer(ui.Modal, title="Edit Footer"):
        ftext = ui.TextInput(label="Edit footer text", placeholder="Encourage life", style=discord.TextStyle.long, required=False)
        fticon = ui.TextInput(label="Edit footer image", placeholder="https://www.chickenCLT.png", style=discord.TextStyle.long, required=False)
        time = ui.TextInput(label="Timestamp", placeholder="Yes/No", style=discord.TextStyle.short, min_length=2, max_length=6, required=False)

        def __init__(self, original_embed: discord.Embed):
            super().__init__()
            if original_embed.footer:
                self.ftext.default = original_embed.footer.text
                self.fticon.default = original_embed.footer.icon_url

        async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
            embed = interaction.message.embeds[0]
            if self.ftext:
                embed.set_footer(text=self.ftext.value, icon_url=self.fticon.value)

            if self.time.value.lower() == "yes":
                embed.timestamp = datetime.now()
            else:
                embed.timestamp = None

            await interaction.message.edit(embed=embed)
            await interaction.response.send_message(".", delete_after=0.0001)


class MainView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


    @discord.ui.button(label="Edit Footer", style=discord.ButtonStyle.grey, custom_id="edit_footer")
    async def edit_footer(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        emb = interaction.message.embeds[0]
        await interaction.response.send_modal(footer(emb))
```